# GGplot graph changes when used with plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, boxplot, ggplotly

I'm trying to make my GGplot interactive with plotly but the graphs change completely given the following code. Any advice on where I may be going wrong is highly appreciated. I have tried to follow some previous posts on this topic but nothing seems to be helping. I have attached my dataset which is number 24 from this list if you want to reproduce this code: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/articles/data.html

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

p2 <- ggplot(data_set,aes(gender, income))+geom_boxplot(aes(fill=private)) 

ggplotly(p2)
p2
```

I have attached photos on how the graph changes when its submitted through plotly:
[image: Plotly generated graph]

vs normal GGplot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to plotly:  `layout(boxmode = "group")`

```
ggplotly(p2) %>% 
  layout(boxmode = "group")
```

[image]